# css ::after block for tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made something like a self-written tooltip, now when I hover over the icon, I have this

[image]

But I can’t understand a little how to remove unnecessary borders and make a normal background so that everything looks correct, something like this

[image]

I have tried many options, and what I have now is the maximum that I could, and so far I can not come to a decision

```css
.wrapper {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:url('https://i.imgur.com/ZzNCjw4.jpg');
}

.tooltip-info {
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
  left:200px;
}

.tooltip-info .tooltip-text {
  width:150px;
  position:absolute;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:8px;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:500;
  visibility:hidden;
  transition-delay:0.1s;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter:blur(4px);
  backdrop-filter:blur(4px);
  border:1px solid white;
}

.tooltip-info .tooltip-text::after {
  content: '';
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter:blur(4px);backdrop-filter:blur(4px);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent white white transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 87%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0) rotate(45deg);
}

.tooltip-info .tooltip-text a {
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:yellow;
}

.tooltip-info:hover .tooltip-text {
  visibility:visible;
  transform:translateY(-55px) translateX(-75px);
}

.tooltip-info .icon {
  color:white !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tooltip-info">
    <div class="tooltip-text">For more information <br> <a href="google.com">click here</a></div>
    <i class="icon fa fa-info-circle"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

This answer does not solve my question [CSS only tooltip with arrow and border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178202/css-only-tooltip-with-arrow-and-border)

`background:inherit;` will not help me in any way, since I have a image background

Comment: The duplicate answer is one solution. Another solution is to use 2 `::after` pseudo elements instead of 1. Normally you create your element that contains the text and a pseudo element that contains the triangle for the speech bubble. The problem with this, as you've already discovered, is the borders. The solution is to put a second pseudo element on top of the first one with the same background as the bubble, hence creating a single bordered speech bubble. Hadn't finished it yet, but here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/rsjxy8mL/

Comment: Sorry to see it is closed. Here is the answer I prepared: [Solution](https://codepen.io/rakibul2010islam/pen/yLQGzev)